# $N$ random points make a random polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, lagrange-interpolation

Let's say I have a finite field $A$, and I choose $N$ (distinct) points uniformly at random from $A \times A$. Then using Lagrange interpolation I can find a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $N-1$ that goes through all my points. Is $f$ a random polynomial? That is, are its coefficients also uniform at random?

Comment: Is $f$ a function from $A$ to $A$?

Comment: Yes. That should be so because I said I was picking points from $A \times A$, right?

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but when picking random points, you could pick two points with the same $x$ and a different $y$. I guess you want to exclude those situations, but that should be made clear.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to tell about background of your question. Thanks.

Comment: The question is motivated by Shamir's secret sharing scheme: pick coefficients at random except for the constant term, which is your secret. If I create the polynomial using random points instead, does it ensure that nobody can learn anything about the secret if they know only some of the coefficients?